# Angular Electron - showOpenDialog typescript errors? no properties in common with type 'OpenDialogOptions'

Tags: angular, typescript, electron

I'm trying to use Electron's native dialog support in order to open a file and I keep running into this typescript issue that I can't seem to get around:

```
[ts] Type '(folderPath: any) => void' has no properties in common with type 'OpenDialogOptions'.
```

Here is my code:

```
import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron'

export class ChartOfAccountsComponent implements OnInit {


public electronDialog = new ElectronService().remote.dialog;

openImport() {
    let properties: any = {
      title: "Import budget",
      properties: ['openDirectory']
    }

    this.electronDialog.showOpenDialog(properties, (folderPath) => {
      if (folderPath === undefined){
          console.log("You didn't select a folder");
          return;
      }
      console.log('folderPath', folderPath);
    });
  }
}
```

Is there something I can do to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

`showOpenDialog` returns a type of `OpenDialogReturnValue`:

```
  interface OpenDialogReturnValue {
    /**
     * whether or not the dialog was canceled.
     */
    canceled: boolean;
    /**
     * An array of file paths chosen by the user. If the dialog is cancelled this will
     * be an empty array.
     */
    filePaths: string[];
    /**
     * An array matching the `filePaths` array of base64 encoded strings which contains
     * security scoped bookmark data. `securityScopedBookmarks` must be enabled for
     * this to be populated. (For return values, see table here.)
     *
     * @platform darwin,mas
     */
    bookmarks?: string[];
  }
```

What you want is something like this:

```
this.electronDialog.showOpenDialog(properties, (value: OpenDialogReturnValue) => {
      if (value.canceled){
          console.log("You didn't select a folder");
          return;
      }
      console.log('folderPaths', value.filePaths);
    });
```